# PDF Quartz Rendering quality

Tags: ipad, pdf, quartz-graphics

On the iPad, I need to render a large pdf (more than 1gb). For this I use Quartz.

Now everything works fine except the quality of included pdf in my pdf.

I'm using `CGContextDrawPDFPage` to render the pdf into the UIView context (in drawRect).

Comment: They, do, but you have to compose them.

Comment: Got enough rep to fix the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
```

Before drawing the pdf page and everything is fine.